# Stub camel route bean reference for integration test

Tags: apache-camel, integration-testing

I have a camel route which has a bean pointing to a amazon wrapper class.  That class is making an amazon call.

Ideally I would like to stub out the amazon call for the integration test.

However all I can think of is to put a split on the route to check for a particular flag. If the flag is positive then the code calls thr stub and if its negative then it calls actual amazon.

I really do not like this option  as it is mixing production code with test code. Or is it ok in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [advices](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) for this scenario..

If you need help with it, please Post an example Route that demonstrates your Problem.